# 2D array of an abstract class?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, abstract-class

I'm having a difficult time with abstract arrays.  In my current case, I want to have a 2D array of an abstract class called `Base`.  So I made a pointer to a 2D array of `Base` in a class called `Container`.  How do I access the items inside of the array?  Also, can someone confirm that I am deleting my array properly?  Thanks in advance for any help!

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void abstract() = 0;
};

//----------------------------------

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void abstract();
};

void Derived::abstract()
{
    // empty
}

//----------------------------------

class Container
{
public: 
    Board();
    virtual ~Board();
    Base* bases[8][8];
};

// Constructor
Container::Container()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            bases[i][j] = new Derived();
}

// Destructor
Container::~Container()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        delete [] bases[i];
    delete [] bases;
}

//----------------------------------

int main()
{
    Container container;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>>`?

Comment: @moshbear I have not.  I will give that a try

Comment: @moshbear So will a `shared_ptr` only handle my memory allocation problems?

Comment: Another advantage of `vector` and `shared_ptr` is that deletion happens inside `shared_ptr`'s destructor, so you don't have to worry about memory leaks. If your C++ compiler isn't C++11-compatible (pre-gcc-4.4, pre-VS-10), the equivalent is Boost's smart_ptr.

Comment: Also, make use of `vector`'s `(count, val)` constructor, like so:
`std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>> x (8, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>(8, std::shared_ptr<Base>(new Derived)));`

Answer (score 2):

There are no arrays to `delete[]` here. You don't `new[]` any array, why should you `delete[]` them?

You do need to delete *each individual element*, which is not the same as `delete[]`ing the arrays:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        delete bases[i][j];
```

And make sure your `Base` has a virtual destructor!

---

```
bases[8][8] = new Derived();
```

Ooops. The array indices only go up to 7! I suspect you intended to write `bases[i][j] = new Derived()`.

Comment: I thought that since I created `Derived` classes with `new` and assigned the pointers to spots in the `bases` array, I would have to delete them.  Is this not correct?  Surely I have to delete the `Derived` classes I instantiate at some point?

Comment: Sorry, `bases[8][8]` was a typo.  It's supposed to be `bases[i][j]`.